# C# Outlook 2010 AddIn Display form with Background Image when new Email is received

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-addins

I am trying to do a simple task, display a form with a background image whenever a new email is received in outlook 2010. I can get the form to display when outlook launches without a problem, so I believe the issue is related to my code recognizing the new email.  I’m still fairly new to C# so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have included the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.NewMail += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailEventHandler(ThisAddIn_NewMail);
    }

    void ThisAddIn_NewMail()
    {
        Form bam = new Form();
        bam.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\\Bam.jpg");
        bam.Width = 321;
        bam.Height = 613;
        bam.Show();
     }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region VSTO generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to write in startup event:
            Application.NewMail += Application_NewMail;

I tried the code with this change and it works!
What is a problem?